# How to write equivalent code of SAS macro parameter in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

need some support on create and write equivalent code of SAS macro parameter in python by **using def function.**
If yes please help me and I am trying to automate below code in python.

**Apologies, I don't know how to insert excel file data here,
but below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPsqJ.png)I have inserted data image its only 20rows data, for your reference.**

/***** Convert SAS Macro parameter in Pyspark or python****/

/*Creating table test1 and below its variable*/
/*metric_name, sex, metric_value,   metric_base,bas_calc_flag ,legal_entity*/
/*Created empty structure table test_data_3 based on where I can insert below final output.*/

```
proc sql;
create table test_1 as
select 'age_male' as metric_name ,
sex,
sum(Height) as metric_value,
sum(Weight) as metric_base,
1 as bas_calc_flag,
'ABC' as legal_entity
from sashelp.class
group by 1,2,5,6
order by 1,2,5,6; quit;
 
 data test_1;
 set test_1 ;
 drop sex; run;

 proc sql;
 create table test_2 like test_1;
 quit;

 %macro test_macro(metnam,sex, measuresuf, measurebase, bas_flag);
proc sql;
create table test_3 as
select 
&metnam as metric_name,
sum(&measuresuf) as metric_value,
sum(&measurebase) as metric_base,
&bas_flag as bas_calc_flag,
'ABC' as legal_entity
 from sashelp.class
 where sex =  &sex
 group by 1,4,5
 order by 1,4,5; quit;
 
 proc sql;
 create table test_4 as
 select * from test_3; quit; 

 /**inserting final output in below empty table */
 proc sql;
 insert into  test_2 
 select * from  test_4; quit;

 %mend;
 %test_macro('H_Feml','F',Height ,Weight, 1);
 %test_macro('H_male','M',Height ,Weight, 1);
 %test_macro('age_male','M',Age ,Weight, 1);
 %test_macro('age_Feml','F',Age ,Weight, 1);

 proc sql;
 select * from test_2; quit; 
 ****here is output image[enter image description here][2]****
```

Comment: The macro 'test_macro' would simply convert to a Python function. The macro inputs to function  parameters. %local_connect_to_teradata is btw another macro/function which most likeyl contains something like 'connect to teradata(<user vars>)'.

Comment: Hi there. Could you explain what the code is doing. What do you input into the code and what is your output in SAS? Could you give an example of a data set you are using in SAS?